# Spring default objects creation?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

does Spring read any configuration file from where it comes to know that some default out of the box implementations are to be created (`HandlerMapping`, `ViewResolver` etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, `DispatcherServlet.properties` in the `org.springframework.web.servlet` pacakge is the what you looking for.

Related snippet from the DispatcherServlet sources:

```
 /**
  * Name of the class path resource (relative to the DispatcherServlet class)
  * that defines DispatcherServlet's default strategy names.
  */
 private static final String DEFAULT_STRATEGIES_PATH ="DispatcherServlet.properties";

 ....

 static {
    // Load default strategy implementations from properties file.
    // This is currently strictly internal and not meant to be customized
    // by application developers.
    try {
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource(DEFAULT_STRATEGIES_PATH, DispatcherServlet.class);
        defaultStrategies = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not load 'DispatcherServlet.properties': " + ex.getMessage());
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.. Can u please tell me how does does the spring create these objects after reading info this properties file? I am not talking about the getBean() method which simply returns the preexisting Object from the 'ApplicationContext', rather I am talking about how these objects are created inside the 'ApplicationContext'

Comment: You can look into `DispatcherServlet#getDefaultStrategies` method. These objects are not from *ApplicationContext*. Spring grabs a listed classes, and then invokes `AutowireCapableBeanFactory#createBean(Class)` for each one.  *DispatcherServlet* do these objects registration in an *ApplicationContext*.